# Fatal Error in LoadRunner 2020 installation

Tags: installation, loadrunner

1. Tried to install the new LR 2020 community (LoadRunner_2020_Community_Edition_Micro_Focus_LoadRunner_2020_Community_Edition.exe).
2. Machine is Windows 10 Pro. Version: 1809. OS build: 17763.615
3. Made LR full installation.
4. Got error that stopped the installation: "

MSI (s) (7C:D4) [16:00:30:645]: Note: 1: 1935 2: {E4678501-4B3A-4F63-972A-F510D0EF5B65} 3: 0x8007028A 4: IAssemblyCacheItem 5: Commit 6: log4net,fileVersion="1.2.10.0",version="1.2.10.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="1B44E1D426115821",processorArchitecture="MSIL" MSI (s) (7C:D4) [16:00:30:645]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error
MSI (s) (7C:D4) [16:00:30:645]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1935
Error 1935. An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'log4net,fileVersion="1.2.10.0",version="1.2.10.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="1B44E1D426115821",processorArchitecture="MSIL"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8007028A. assembly interface: IAssemblyCacheItem, function: Commit, component: {E4678501-4B3A-4F63-972A-F510D0EF5B65}"

Comment: I will forward to the installation team

Answer (score 1):

We are not familiar with this kind of error during the installation.

However, I have a few suggestions that might help:

First, make sure you run the installation as administrator.

If that still doesn’t work, please refer to the following article that might help solving the issue: https://windowsreport.com/fix-windows-10-error-1935/

Please try and update.

Thanks, Yulia,
Micro Focus R&D

Comment: Passed through most of the recommendations with out sucess. Do you recommend any "Solution 6 – Install Visual C++ Redistributables" installation?

Answer (score 0):

Have this check too: restart the machine and check if **.Net Framework 4.8** is installed - then rerun the setup.

In Registry Editor, open the following subkey: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full**.

**Release** should be:

On Windows 10 May 2019 Update and Windows 10 November 2019 Update: **528040**

On all other Windows operating systems (including other Windows 10 operating systems): **528049**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

If not - it should have been installed - but you can manually install it to by pass this faster. Then rerun the setup.

Comment: Verified and in my case "On all other Windows operating systems (including other Windows 10 operating systems): 528049". Then reinstall and failed again.